# How to get a value from Publisher response Micronaut

Tags: micronaut, reactive-streams

I'm using Micronaut and I need to get the response from a doFilter like Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<*>>, but in the unit test, I can't get the value response in the stream. Can Someone Help me?

[image: The image show the answer of the request]

Comment: Can you provide some more code example? I would say you probably have to .subscribe to the Publisher. Make sure you get your Reactive fundamentals in place. :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. I forgot to use .subscribe

Comment: I’ll post it also as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `.subscribe()` to a Publisher to get the emitted values. Make sure to get your Reactive 101 in place!